# Assigning JS promises value to a variable

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

As a starter in JS promises it is a bit confusing to me, I am trying to get a base64 of an image using this function :

```
const convertFileToBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 const reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
 reader.onerror = reject;
})
```

when I call this function I get a promise I can use .then to print the value, but I cannot assign the returned value of the function to a variable .

Comment: can you show how you're calling the function? the returned value should be the parameter to your first function in the `.then` as in `.then(result => {})`

Comment: I have this function

```const handleFile = async (file) => {
  return await convertFileToBase64(file)
}```

and this is called in another function  ```const res= handleFile(icon)```
printing res will output a promise

Comment: so you should use `res.then(result => { /* use result */ }` as described in my answer

Answer (score 1):

When calling a function that returns a `Promise` there are 2 ways to get the result from it:

1. using `.then`
2. using async/await

**.then approach:**

```
convertFileToBase64(myFile)
  .then(result => {
    // do something with the result within this little function
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle any error
  });
```

**async/await approach:**

```
// must be inside an async function
async function doSomething() {
  const result = await convertFileToBase64(myFile);  // wait and assign result to variable
  // do something with the result
  // errors can get handled by whoever calls this async function
}
```

Comment: I know that I can ```.then``` to access the value but lets say I want to do something like this 
```let finalResult = {}
            convertFileToBase64(icon).then(r => {
              finalResult = r
            })
            console.log('final result :', finalResult)```

the output will be undefined

Comment: if you don't want to use `.then` you have to use `await` instead